# How to add hyperling to grid printing - Devexpress Xpf Printing

Tags: c#, devexpress, .net-4.8, devexpress-wpf, devexpress-gridcontrol

I need your help.

I am using Printing talent of Devexpress v17.2. And my application is a WPF application. I get to current grids as PrintTableControl and showing in PrintPreview.

Bu now I need to add HyperLink to Print. I want to add Hyperlink which is get from model.

Here is printing code:

```
var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
foreach (var link in this.printTableControls.Select(printTableControl => new PrintTableControlLink(printTableControl){
     Margins = new Margins (2,2,2,2)
})){
    link.PrintingSystem.ExportOptions.PrintPreview.DefaultDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    link.PrintingSystem.ExportOptions.PrintPreview.SaveMode = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.SaveMode.UsingDefaultPath;
    var window = PrintHelper.ShowPrintPreview(parent, link);
    window.Title = Resource.Title
}
```

This code gets current grids or tables and shows to user. After Previewing user can select to save as file like excel, word, pdf etc. I need to add Hyperlink. Hyperlink should work when user save as file.

How can I do that? If I add Hyperlink to grid can I achieve what I want? If I can how can I add hyperlink to grid column?
(I will get hyperlink from ViewModel property)

Thanks a lot.